# Controlling speed & direction of 3 DC motors via RPi

Tags: pwm

i'm planning my very first robot
What's the simpliest way to Control speed (using PWM) & direction of 3 DC motors via Raspberry Pi ?
is it correct that Rpi has 1 PWM Pin ? 
i mean can I use it to PWM 3 of DC motors?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The early Pi's with the 26 pin expansion header have one available hardware PWM pin (connected to GPIO 18).

The recent Pi's with the 40 pin expansion header have four available hardware PWM pins (connected to GPIO 12/13/18/19).

Although recent Pi's have 4 pins there are only two channels as 12 has the same setting as 18 and 13 has the same setting as 19.  This means that effectively there are only two hardware PWM pins available.

However software timed PWM is available on all GPIO and may be adequate to control simple motors.  The overhead of software timing may impact on processing time depending on the frequency used.

As an alternative my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library will generate hardware timed PWM on all accessible GPIO.

This type of PWM is very similar to that provided on the Arduino.  On the Pi it defaults to 800Hz with 250 steps between off and fully on.

See [set_PWM_dutycycle](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_dutycycle).

This PWM does not utilise CPU time.

Comment: thanks
so using RPi with 40 pin is good to  "hardware PWM" 3 DC motors correct ?

Comment: Yes, the Pi can provide suitable PWM.